# Xcode iOS label resizes UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I am developing an app where I have this problem, regarding showing some products.

The product cell consists of an image and a label under it.

The image and label is inside a UIView because I need corner radius and shadow around the image and label.

But if the label text increases it will resize my image and make it smaller instead of making the parent UIView height larger.

Does anyone know or have an example for that? I want to tell it that it should make the parent UIView bigger instead of making the image inside the UIView smaller.

Image of my problem:
[image]

Comment: Is this a collection view? Can you show what code you have so far?

Comment: Hi. Yes I will upload it soon. I am using the CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout from GitHub. It is a collection view and I just throw an height and width to the CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout and then it renders it. So not much code from my site.
My XIB file then has a view inside that is constrained to all sides with a little margin. Inside the view I have a image at top constrained to top, left and right. Under image I have a label constrained top = bottom of image, left, right and bottom constrain to bottom of the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
let ratioConstId = "ratio_const"
if let ratioConst = ivPetIcon.constraints.first(where: { $0.identifier == ratioConstId }) {
    ivPetIcon.removeConstraint(ratioConst)
}
let ratio = ivPetIcon.image!.size.height / ivPetIcon.image!.size.width
let const = ivPetIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: ratio)
const.isActive = true
const.identifier = ratioConstId
```